# Attempting to Post String to PHP dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, dynamic

Using JavaScript only I want to POST a string to php file and redirect to it at the same time, however, my php file is not picking up the information.

JavaScript:

```
    var data = "&id=" + obj.id;
    var redirect = function(url, method) {
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.method = method;
        form.action = url;
        form.value = data;
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    };

   redirect("summary.php","POST");
```

And the PHP code is simply (NO ERROR HERE, JUST FOR CONVENIENCE):

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

EDIT:

The problem is that the PHP file is not picking up the name "id". There is no problem in the php file or how I structure my data.

Comment: `$id` not `&id`

Comment: at the NETWORK inspector do you see the variable id posted with a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you pass the data. `value` is a property of a form's input element, not the form itself.

So remove the line `form.value = data;` and replace with

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name = 'id';
input.value = obj.id;
form.appendChild(input);
```

Now you should be able to get `$_POST['id']`.

Comment: Yea this gave me the solution, although I did figure it out on my own, this was the way I did it.

Answer (score 2):

You made a small typo. ALthough it is a huge problem. In PHP you create variables using the `$` sign.

```
var data = "id=" + obj.id;//you don't necessarilly need the & as you are only passing one item(value)


    var redirect = function(url, method) {
                var form = document.createElement('form');
                form.method = method;
                form.action = url;
                //form.value = data;//this won't work. form does not have value attribute:
                //create input element
               var i = document.createElement("input");
               i.type = "text";//set type.
               i.name = "id";//set name of the input
               i.id = "id";
               i.value = obj.id;//set value of input
               form.appendChild(i);//add this input to the form
               document.body.appendChild(form);//add the form to the body
                form.submit();//dynamically submit
            };

       redirect("summary.php","POST");
```

In your php script, access it like

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);//show all errors and notices
$id = $_POST['id'];//you forgot the $ sign
//for debugging, check the post array 
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Make sure the `obj.id` is not null

Comment: That is not the problem, I can assure you. Its just because I typed it out. Its fixed in the orginal file. Will fix here

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: The console says that it can't find an object with the correct name as "id". But I found a solution. Will post it up later.

Comment: i added a solution. you can also look at it